# Differentiating between an observable being disposed due to an error vs completion

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a subscription that looks something like the below:

```
public IObservable<Item> GetItems()
{
  return from batch in CreateItemsObservable()
  .OnDispose(() => Console.Writeline("disposed")
  select batch
}
```

OnDispose is an extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnDispose<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Action onDispose)
{
  return Observable.Create<T>(
    observer => new CompositeObservable(observable.Subscribe(
      observer.OnNext,
      observer.OnError,
      observer.OnCompleted), Disposable.Create(onDispose)));
}
```

What I would like to do if possible is differentiate between dispose being called because the stream was completed/explicitly unsubscribed vs when it is disposed due to an error.

Is there a way to modify OnDispose to indicate the reason?  I was looking at possibly utilizing Materialize to somehow pass along the notification to the dispose action but not sure where I would apply it or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so very close:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnDispose<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<NotificationKind> disposed) =>
    Observable
        .Create<T>(o =>
        {
            Notification<T> last = null;
            return new CompositeDisposable(
                source.Materialize().Do(x => last = x).Dematerialize().Subscribe(o),
                Disposable.Create(() => disposed(last == null ? NotificationKind.OnNext : last.Kind)));
        });
```

Now I kind of cheated and used `NotificationKind` to indicate if unsubscribed (without being completed or errored) by using `NotificationKind.OnNext`. If you want to create you're own `enum` to more clearly indicate the result then you should.